# Incorrect syntax of sp_rename

Tags: sql-server

I want to rename **team** view to **myteam**.

```sql
create view team as (select * from employees);
```

I'm writing the `sp_rename` command but it, showing error.

```sql
sp_rename team myteam;
```

```
[12:31:15 pm]   Started executing query at Line 685
    
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'myteam'. 
    
    Total execution time: 00:00:00.012
```

Answer (score 1):

`sp_rename` syntax:

```sql
sp_rename old_name, new_name;
```

There is a `,` between old_name and new_name.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:
sp_rename 'old_table_object', 'new_table_object'

The result outputs of this procedure might be 0 or non-zero values. 0 value indicates that the procedure execution successfully completed and non-zero values indicate failure.

[How to rename tables in SQL Server with the sp_rename command](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-rename-tables-in-sql-server-with-the-sp_rename-command/)